# Unable to build on ios device after updating sdk to 5.2.2

Tags: ios, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

Sdk pompt of failing build while deploying to IOS device while everything works on simulator.

** BUILD FAILED **

[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
Ld build/T***.build/Debug-iphoneos/T***-universal.build/Objects-normal/armv7/T*** 
normal armv7

This is happening after I updated my studio to 5.2.2 .
I have tried using my old as well as latest sdk but no luck

Comment: Did you try clean build? You can remove build and resources folder manually too and try it.

Comment: Tried that already but no success . Cleaning build seems to be default step when something is not working properly (in case of Titanium )